# BEP-20 Contract - Claim Name of contract

Tags: bep20

A very newbie question here, but is there a way to claim a BEP-20 token name kind of like buying a domain address? I understand that the contract is immutable so once deployed the contract is immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the decentralized nature of smart contracts, there's no central database that token creators would need to verify their token name against.

You can deploy the same token contract (including the same constructor parameters) virtually unlimited amount of times. Each time it' s going to have a different address, but also each time it's going to have the same token name.